# How to add two matrices in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to know how I can add two matrices in VBA:

```
Sub add_two_matrices()
Dim A As Variant
Dim B as Variant
A = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Location_of_A").Range("A1: A5")
B = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Location_of_B").Range("A1: A5")
```

where A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and B = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
I want to obtain C = A + B, which is [3, 5, 7, 9, 11]

Comment: Do you want a **Sub** or a **function**??

Comment: I am sorry, but I am new to VBA and do not really know the difference between the two. I am actually writing Sub and wnat to add two matrices inside that sub.

Comment: @JunJang A function is an atomic piece of code that does something; a sub(routine) is typically a 'program' within VBA that can house many functions.

Comment: `Function` can return result, and can be used in Excel Formula. `Sub` can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but closest you'd get would be:

**Edit2:** Incorporating `Transpose` both below will return a 1D array.

```
Dim c, i As Integer
c = Evaluate("Transpose(Location_of_A!A1:A5)+Transpose(Location_of_B!A1:A5)")

'/* loop to check the values */
For i = LBound(c) To UBound(c)
    Debug.Print c(i)
Next
```

You can also use `MMULT WorksheetFunction` to get what you want.

```
Dim a, b, c, i As Integer

With Application
    a = .Transpose(Sheets("Location_of_A").Range("A1:A5"))
    b = .Transpose(Sheets("Location_of_B").Range("A1:A5"))
    c = .WorksheetFunction.MMult(Array(1, 1), Array(a, b))
End With

'/* loop to check values */
For i = LBound(c) To UBound(c)
    Debug.Print c(i)
Next
```

Above works because your values are within worksheet.
If however you need a pure VBA solution, you'll have to loop.